# How to use != in a switch statement?

Tags: ios, swift, uibutton, switch-statement

Currently we have a cell with 5 buttons, when one button is pressed it will turn white while all other buttons will turn black.  There is a separate checkmark imageview on the button that will be checked or unchecked depending if the button is selected.  So fat this works for the imageView:

```
 @IBAction func changeColor(_ sender: Any) {
        guard let button = sender as? UIButton else {
            return
        }

        self.selectedCheckMarkImageView1.isHidden = button.tag != 1
        self.selectedCheckMarkImageView2.isHidden = button.tag != 2
        self.selectedCheckMarkImageView3.isHidden = button.tag != 3
        self.selectedCheckMarkImageView4.isHidden = button.tag != 4
        self.selectedCheckMarkImageView5.isHidden = button.tag != 5
}
```

but when trying to use the same approach for changing button image:

```
 button.setImage(UIImage(named: "LR - Nano White - Selected")!, for: .normal) = button.tag != 1
```

an error occurs:

> Cannot assign to value: function call returns immutable value

I tried putting it in a switch statement like this:

```
  switch (button.tag) {

        case != 1: //error occurs here


        default:
           //
        }
```

but get the error:

> '!=' is not a prefix unary operator

Any idea on how to solve this issue?

Comment: case should have an `Int` because tag is `Int` ?

Comment: remove `!=` and just check matching cases e.g. `case 1:`

Comment: You should re-make your `@IBOutlet`, and simply pick the parameter type to be `UIButton` instead of `Any`. That way, no casting (forced, or conditional) would be required.

Answer (score 2):

A switch is a replacement for 1 value being compared against a fix set of multiple values other values, to pick a single branch of execution to take. You have a situation in which multiple values are checked against multiple different values, and doing multiple different things in response. A single switch can't really replace that.

Instead, I suggest reduce repetition by using a `for` loop.

```
let selectedCheckMarkImageViews = [
    selectedCheckMarkImageView1,
    selectedCheckMarkImageView2,
    selectedCheckMarkImageView3,
    selectedCheckMarkImageView4,
    selectedCheckMarkImageView5,
]

let visbleImageViewIndex = button.tag // TODO: either number these 0..<4, or add 1 below
for (index, view) in selectedCheckMarkImageViews.enumerated() {
    view.isHidden = visbleImageViewIndex != index
}
```

Comment: I was trying to figure out a way to explain this! _clap_ _clap_

Comment: @Alexander this works great with hiding/unhiding imageViews but what I'm trying to do is change the background image of a button to 'selected', 'unselected' using the same concept

Comment: @SwiftyJD So? What's the issue? Just expand on this: `let isSelected = visbleImageViewIndex == index; view.isHidden = !isSelected; view.backgroundImage = isSelected ? selectedImage : deselectedImage`

Comment: @Alexander I don't think I properly explained what I'm trying to do.  I'm trying to change a button (ex.  button.setImage(unselectedImage, for: .normal)) with an array of unique selected images and an array of unique unselected images.  When a button is tapped it should display that specific selected image on button based on index, and all other buttons will automatically display the unselected image.  The code you provided work well with imageviews but this is a bit different since its doing something like:  button.setImage(unselectedImage, for: .normal)

Comment: @SwiftyJD You only need to set the images once per button per each `UIControl.State` that you care about. Why would you have to change them per button press?

Comment: @Alexander basically there can only be one button with the selected image at a time, so once one button is pressed and shows the selected image(different for each button), when a second button is pressed the first button must switch it's image back to the unselected image. Each button has its own unique selected, and unselected image.

Comment: @SwiftyJD That's what UIControl.State is for. You set the various images of each button once, and then you don't have to change it ever again

Answer (score 1):

**Try this**

```
switch (button.tag) {

        case _ where button.tag != 1: 


        default:
           //
        }
```

Comment: I tried it, but get an error   case _ where button.tag != 1:
            self.selectedCheckMarkImageView1.isHidden//Expression resolves to an unused l-value

Comment: @SwiftyJD self.selectedCheckMarkImageView1.isHidden --> **isHidden** is a read only property you are not using it so the error

Comment: @SwiftyJD What error are you getting in switch case?

Comment: @SwiftyJD can you share your switch statement code?

Comment: switch button.tag {
  case  _ where button.tag != 1: self.selectedCheckMarkImageView1.isHidden                                 
 case  _ where button.tag != 2: self.selectedCheckMarkImageView2.isHidden  }

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/178479/discussion-between-vinay-kiran-and-swiftyjd).

Comment: @SwiftyJD  Try this
switch button.tag {
    case _ where button.tag != 1: self.selectedCheckMarkImageView1.isHidden = true
    case _ where button.tag != 2: self.selectedCheckMarkImageView2.isHidden = true
    }